# How can I avoid 503 errors in my website/server?

Tags: reactjs, axios, http-status-code-503

Its disguisting really. Its been an entire day, and I keep on getting this 503 error everytime. Is there any mistakes that I have made ? Or is it codeforces ?
Here is my code :-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { Stack } from '@mui/material';
import { ContentContext } from '../../Context/ContentContext';

export default function MediaCard() {
    const { pageData } = React.useContext(ContentContext);

    const input = pageData.subRate;
    let size = 0;
    let sum = 0;
    if (input && typeof input === 'object') {
        size = Object.keys(input).length;
        const values = Object.values(input);
        sum = values.reduce((acc, count) => acc + count, 0);
    } else {
        console.log('input is undefined or null');
    }

    // console.log(rate);
    console.log(sum);

    return (
        <Stack display='flex' alignItems='center' justifyContent='center'>
            <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>

                <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                        XYZ
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                        Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
                        species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>

            </Card>
        </Stack>
    );
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: It's an API error and the code you posted does not seem to use `axio`s. Check your API server if it's hosted by you. This is not an issues with react I guess. But please do post the actual code for the component that is making these requests